# LoadLibrary freezes

Tags: windows, api, dll, loadlibrary

I have compiled a JNI dll that I would like to load into my Java application using `System.loadLibrary`. This works perfectly fine on Windows XP with the dll compiled using MSVC++ 2008 Express.

However, on Windows 7, where I compiled the dll using MSVC++ 2010 Express (same options, same processor architecture, same Java version, just different OS and compiler) the application would freeze upon the `loadLibrary` call. No error messages, no reaction at all. When I try `jstack` on the frozen process it freezes as well (no output, no termination). Running the application as an administrator does not fix this problem.

The DLL and all its dependencies are in the `java.library.path`. In fact, when I removed them, the Java application would tell me they're missing, so the dll must have been initialized properly and something else fails. Debugging proves, however, that it's actually `loadLibrary` freezing and nothing afterwards.

Can anybody tell me what might be going on here?

---

**UPDATE**:

As stated in my comment below, this problem seems to go deeper. Using a simple C program to load one of the dependencies of said DLL already makes the freeze occur, so this must be some kind of problem with the Windows API and how MSVC++ linked the DLL (that dependency was linked by MSVC++ 2010 Express as well).

Comment: OK, this seems to be a deeper problem with DLLs and the Windows API `LoadLibrary`. I have no solution yet, but this has nothing to do with Java at all, because the Windows API is what's freezing when loading a dependency of my DLL. I was able to show that writing a simple C program that uses it.

Comment: Is there a DllMain provided by any of the DLLs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your DLL is almost certainly calling something that tries to obtain the loader lock from inside its [`DLLMain()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682583.aspx).

What you describe is called deadlock and these symptoms fit this particular issue perfectly.

Comment: Yep, from what I just heared from the author there's a known problem with ATI cards when creating an OpenGL context on a global scope. Not sure what to do with this question now, it's a special case and there's no general solution?

Comment: In a sense, it is. It's not actually the `DllMain()`, but it is initializations on static scope that fail, which is pretty much the same in this case.

Comment: Yes that's right. You don't write a DllMain explicitly but the compiler runs your initialisation code from DllMain.

Comment: If you googled this (like I did) because you get such freezes under Windows XP/Windows Server 2003: Make sure to not read blocking from stdin in another thread while doing the loadLibrary. See here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2009703